# hosting a vue js application with laravel on AWS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3

iam using AWS for hosting Laravel app in elastic beanstalk behind a load balancer,
i want to host my vue js app separately, i tried to use S3 , the routing didnt work (when i refreshed the page, it stopped working)
is there any solution with good performance to host vue js separate from Laravel Apis?
thank you

Comment: The routing when you refresh the page of an SPA is going to be an issue with any hosting method. You have to configure the host to perform redirects of those routes. You could do this by placing CloudFront in front of your S3 bucket. Or just change the Error Document setting in the S3 static hosting configuration.

Comment: i created a cloudfront for the s3 bucket, i still face the refresh page error,but how can i fix it after the cloudfront configuration?

Comment: You'll need to configure all 404 errors to redirect to the main page instead of showing 404 errors.

Comment: thanks @MarkB , i deployed amplify and its working fine, i just had one other wuestion if you can answer it i will appreciate you. you can check the link ,thanks again
  https://stackoverflow.com/q/69966089/2080049